# Start Selenium Standalone server with Credentials

Tags: selenium

With

```
java -jar selenium-2.16.1/selenium-server-standalone-2.16.1.jar -port 4444
```

I can start a selenium server and reach itw with my clients.

I can't find how to specify credentials which need to be used for the service.

Comment: Credentials for what?

Comment: To make sure, that only authorized people are using the service (in one case i have to expose the selenium service via internet)

Comment: I don't think there's an option for this "out of the box". I'd go for either a proxy in front of the hub with authentication or VPN.

Comment: Are there any informations how companies like sauce lab are doing this ?

Comment: FYI in my case i solved it with a firewall rule and only allow now access from specific ip's